# Not implemented error with eval function in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am making something with python turtle. The eval function shown below is supposed to run h() or i(). Those are the only functions that work right now, so the only things working is hi or ih or i or h. The console returns a notimplementederror: eval is not yet implemented. I don't understand, as I went into a completely new thing, and put basic code like eval('1'), but that didn't work either. Thanks By the way, I am new to python so I am not good at it, so pleease mind me if I made silly mistakes.

```
import turtle

from time import sleep
ninja = turtle.Turtle()
ninja.hideturtle()
coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()
coordinate2 = ninja.ycor()
new1=''
new2=''

ninja.speed(10)
def h():
  ninja.left(90)
  ninja.forward(50)
  ninja.back(100)
  ninja.forward(50)
  ninja.right(90)
  ninja.forward(35)
  ninja.left(90)
  ninja.forward(-50)
  ninja.forward(100)
  coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()
  coordinate2 = ninja.ycor()
  new1 = coordinate1+50

  ninja.penup()
  ninja.goto(new1,0)

def i():
  ninja.forward(20)
  ninja.pendown()

  ninja.left(90)

  ninja.st()
  ninja.right(90)
  ninja.stamp()

  ninja.ht()
  ninja.penup()
  ninja.back(20)
  ninja.pendown()
  ninja.back(50)



  coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()

  new1 = coordinate1+50

  ninja.penup()
  ninja.goto(new1,0)



h()
i()
name = input('What is your name. It will be drawn in the tab to the left lowercase only please.')
print('The name will begin to draw in the tab to the left')
sleep(3)
ninja.clear()
ninja.goto(0,0)

name =  list(name)
print(name)
length = len(name)
x=0
while (x < length-1):         
  print(name[x])
  x = x + 1

  new2=name[x]+'()'
  print(new2)
  eval(new2)
```

Comment: You're running this on some sort of nonstandard interpreter, I would guess some sort of browser-based Javascript thing. Get a "real" Python.

Comment: (Also don't use `eval`, but getting a better Python interpreter is important for other reasons too.)

Comment: @user2357112 I use repl.it I dont know what else to use sorry

Comment: What alternatives do you recommend. And also, is repl.it bad. So, is my code wrong, or my interpreter?

Comment: repl.it should be fine with `eval`. This code fails for a completely different reason when I try it on repl.it; you can't use turtle on repl.it, because it relies on GUI stuff that doesn't work over their setup.

Comment: Okay, so do you have any other online resources I can use? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Install Python on your computer.

Comment: At the moment, I am unable to install python on my computer, sorry. Any other alternatives?

Comment: Perhaps you need the repl.it for python with turtle: https://repl.it/languages/python_turtle...?

Comment: @combinatorist I am using the python with turtle thanks though

Comment: Oh, there's a separate python-with-turtle option on repl.it? Looks like *that* one uses some sort of weird nonstandard interpreter (trinket?), and the regular Python option uses standard CPython. Anyway, don't use `eval`. I'd probably make a dispatch dict manually, but `globals()` is also an option. Longer term, try to reach a point where you can use a local Python install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need nor want `eval()` to implement this program -- you can do it with a dictionary that maps characters to functions.  Below's a simplified rework of your code that uses a dictionary instead of `eval()`:

```
import turtle

def h():
    ninja.pendown()
    ninja.left(90)
    ninja.forward(100)
    ninja.backward(50)
    ninja.right(90)
    ninja.forward(40)
    ninja.left(90)
    ninja.forward(50)
    ninja.backward(100)
    ninja.right(90)

    ninja.penup()
    ninja.forward(25)

def i():
    ninja.forward(20)
    ninja.left(90)
    ninja.forward(70)
    ninja.right(90)
    ninja.pendown()
    ninja.circle(5)

    ninja.penup()
    ninja.left(90)
    ninja.backward(20)
    ninja.pendown()
    ninja.backward(50)
    ninja.right(90)

    ninja.penup()
    ninja.forward(45)

letters_to_code = {"h": h, "i": i}

name = input('What is your name? Lowercase only please: ')

ninja = turtle.Turtle()
ninja.penup()

for letter in name:
    if letter in letters_to_code:
        letters_to_code[letter]()

ninja.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

Some things to think about:

- Have a standard letter *height*, *width* and *spacing* distance and define them as variables that you can use when implmenenting your letters.
- Have each letter leave the turtle in its original starting orientation when it finishes, for the benefit of the next letter.  This will allow you to combine letters in any order without surprises.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet if you're using trinket is to draw out all the letter functions from a to z and use if statements specifying which letters to print out and maximum number of letters to be printed to the screen depending on how big you drew each letter. This is the first time I've seen trinket, I must admit it was somewhat enjoyable and somewhat frustrating at the same time.

I thought we were all stuck in a Cache-22 because trinket.io/python doesn't accept eval or globals, however repl.it accepts the use of eval and globals, but repl.it doesn't have the turtle screen.

#### "cdlane was here to save the day"

**Thanks to cdlane's answer, I know a way around not using globals().**

I experimented all different ways with eval, exec, and globals(), but Interactive Python 3 Trinket online didn't accept any of those methods.

The code will print out momo or AstroBoy from a function if that exact name is entered. Those are the only letters supported. If any of those letters are typed in a different order, the results may be somewhat upredictable output but still enjoyable. Test by typing "mo", "momo", "mom", "astro", "astroboy", "boy", "bboy", "oboy", "yo boy", "robot", etc.

A checkName(name) function and if statements were written to inspire anyone to draw an alphabet of functions and to now use a known work around to not being able to use globals(). (by using the long if-else monster, **or by using cdlane's genius answer**)

Although it was fun to explore the joys of Trinket, I probably won't be playing with trinket again any time soon, or maybe I will comeback to Trinket some time in the distant future. If I do, I won't be spending much time on Trinket because I am starting to learn about Pygame, therefore Pygame is my next scheduled experience.

#### cdlane is getting an upvote!

Enjoy!

## Tested at https://trinket.io/python

```
# Tested at https://trinket.io/python
# Written by AstroBoy R (featuring mOmO)
# Also featuring cdlane's workaround instead of using globals

import turtle

from time import sleep
ninja = turtle.Turtle()
ninja.hideturtle()
coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()
coordinate2 = ninja.ycor()
new1=''
new2=''

ninja.speed(10)
def h():
  ninja.left(90)
  ninja.forward(50)
  ninja.back(100)
  ninja.forward(50)
  ninja.right(90)
  ninja.forward(35)
  ninja.left(90)
  ninja.forward(-50)
  ninja.forward(100)
  coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()
  coordinate2 = ninja.ycor()
  new1 = coordinate1+50

  ninja.penup()
  ninja.goto(new1,0)

def i():
  ninja.forward(20)
  ninja.pendown()

  ninja.left(90)

  ninja.st()
  ninja.right(90)
  ninja.stamp()

  ninja.ht()
  ninja.penup()
  ninja.back(20)
  ninja.pendown()
  ninja.back(50)



  coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()

  new1 = coordinate1+50

  ninja.penup()
  ninja.goto(new1,0)



h()
i()

name = input('What is your name. It will be drawn in the tab to the left lowercase only please.')
print('The name will begin to draw in the tab to the left')
sleep(3)
#ninja.clear()
ninja.goto(0,0)
print(name)

# "AstroBoy's Turtle Program (mOmO remix)"

from turtle import *

def m():
  pendown()
  begin_fill()
  left(90)
  forward(75)
  right(90)
  forward(30)
  print(pos())
  right(70)
  forward(40)
  print(pos())
  left(140)
  forward(40)
  right(70)
  forward(30)
  right(90)
  forward(75)
  right(90)
  forward(30)
  right(90)
  forward(40)
  left(160)
  forward(40)
  right(135)
  forward(40)
  lt(155)
  fd(40)
  rt(90)
  fd(29)
  end_fill()
  penup()
  right(180)
  forward(105)
  print(pos())

def O():
  fd(35)
  pendown()
  begin_fill()
  circle(40)
  end_fill()
  pu()
  left(90)
  fd(30)
  right(90)
  pd()
  begin_fill()
  fillcolor('white')
  circle(10)
  end_fill()
  pu()
  right(90)
  fd(30)
  left(90)
  fd(50)
  print(pos())

def a():
  pd()
  lt(70)
  fd(50)
  rt(140)
  fd(50)
  pu()
  lt(180)
  fd(20)
  lt(70)
  pd()
  fd(22)
  pu()
  lt(90)
  fd(20)
  lt(90)
  fd(30)
  
def s():
  fd(20)
  pd()
  circle(12,-90)
  pu()
  circle(12,90)
  pd()
  circle(12,90)
  circle(12,90)
  circle(-12,270)
  pu()
  fd(36)
  lt(90)
  fd(20)
  
def t():
  fd(5)
  pd()
  lt(90)
  fd(46)
  lt(90)
  fd(20)
  rt(180)
  fd(40)
  rt(90)
  pu()
  fd(45)
  lt(90)
  fd(10)

def r():
  pd()
  lt(90)
  fd(45)
  rt(90)
  fd(15)
  if name=='robot':
    begin_fill()
    fillcolor('teal')
  circle(-13,180)
  fd(15)
  rt(180)
  fd(10)
  pd()
  if name=='robot':
    end_fill()
  rt(45)
  fd(28)
  lt(45)
  pu()
  fd(18)

def o():
  fd(10)
  pd()
  circle(15,90)
  fd(15)
  circle(15,90)
  fd(5)
  circle(15,90)
  fd(15)
  circle(15,90)
  fd(5)
  pu()
  fd(25)
  print(pos())

def b():
  fd(10)
  lt(90)
  pd()
  begin_fill()
  fillcolor('yellow')
  fd(45)
  rt(90)
  fd(20)
  circle(-11,180)
  fd(10)
  rt(180)
  fd(10)
  circle(-12,180)
  fd(21)
  end_fill()
  pu()
  lt(180)
  fd(47)
  
def y():
  fd(5)
  pd()
  begin_fill()
  fillcolor('green')
  fd(5)
  pencolor('green')
  lt(90)
  pencolor('black')
  fd(45)
  lt(90)
  pencolor('teal')
  fd(20)
  lt(135)
  fd(22)
  rt(45)
  end_fill()
  begin_fill()
  fillcolor('chartreuse')
  pencolor('dark green')
  fd(29)
  lt(90)
  fd(9)
  end_fill()
  begin_fill()
  pencolor('black')
  lt(90)
  fillcolor('lime')
  fd(29)
  rt(45)
  fd(22)
  lt(135)
  fd(20)
  end_fill()
  pu()
  rt(180)
  fd(30)
  rt(90)
  fd(45)
  lt(90)
  
  
def testingColorfill():
  home()
  pd()
  c=['green','red','orange','blue', 'yellow', 'magenta', 'gold', 'pink', 'lime', 'cyan']
  n=100
  nc=0
  while n >= 10:
    begin_fill()
    fillcolor(c[nc])
    circle(n)
    end_fill()
    n = n-10
    nc += 1

def testingmOmO():
  m()
  
  #Second letter color
  fillcolor('yellow')
  O()
  
  #Third letter color
  fillcolor('dodger blue')
  m()
  
  #Fourthletter color
  fillcolor('green')
  O()
  
  testingColorfill()
  testingAstroBoy()


def testingAstroBoy():
  penup()
  goto(-175, 0)
  goto(-175, -80)
  a()
  s()
  t()
  r()
  o()
  b()
  #color second letter o teal
  begin_fill()
  fillcolor('teal')
  o()
  end_fill()
  y()


#Go to first letter position
penup()
goto(-170, 0)
goto(-170, -160)
fillcolor('crimson')



#testingmOmO()

  



import string
lowerc = string.ascii_lowercase
upperc = string.ascii_uppercase
momo = 'momo'
name = name.lower()

def checkmOmO(name):
  if name == momo or len(name)==4:
    testingmOmO()

wo=True

def checkName(name):
  if len(name) > 8:
    print "Sorry name is too long!"
    return None
  elif 'm' in name and len(name)==4:
    checkmOmO(name)
    return
  else:
    for n in name:
      for i in range(len(lowerc)):
        if i==0 and (n==lowerc[0]):
          a()
        elif i==1 and (n==lowerc[1]):
          b()
        elif i==2 and (n==lowerc[2]):
          pass
        elif i==3 and (n==lowerc[3]):
          pass
        elif i==4 and (n==lowerc[4]):
          pass
        elif i==5 and (n==lowerc[5]):
          pass
        elif i==6 and (n==lowerc[6]):
          pass
        elif i==7 and (n==lowerc[7]):
          pass
        elif i==8 and (n==lowerc[8]):
          pass
        elif i==9 and (n==lowerc[9]):
          pass
        elif i==10 and (n==lowerc[10]):
          pass
        elif i==11 and (n==lowerc[11]):
          pass
        elif i==12 and (n==lowerc[12]):
          m()
        elif i==13 and (n==lowerc[13]):
          pass
        elif i==14 and (n==lowerc[14]):
          if 'm' in name:
            O()
          else:
            global wo
            if 'b' in name and not wo or len(name)<8:
                begin_fill()
                fillcolor('teal')
                o()
                end_fill()
            else:
              wo=False
              o()
        elif i==15 and (n==lowerc[15]):
          pass
        elif i==16 and (n==lowerc[16]):
          pass
        elif i==17 and (n==lowerc[17]):
          r()
        elif i==18 and (n==lowerc[18]):
          s()
        elif i==19 and (n==lowerc[19]):
          t()
        elif i==20 and (n==lowerc[20]):
          pass
        elif i==21 and (n==lowerc[21]):
          pass
        elif i==22 and (n==lowerc[22]):
          pass
        elif i==23 and (n==lowerc[23]):
          pass
        elif i==24 and (n==lowerc[24]):
          y()
        elif i==25 and (n==lowerc[25]):
          pass
        elif i==26 and (n==lowerc[26]):
          pass
        else:
          print("Sorry, that letter is not yet supported!")


checkName(name)



# cdlane's answer is great and works perfect
# if only I seen this answer before i wrote the if-else monster
# I will be giving cdlane an uptick
"""
# testing
letters_to_code = {'a': a}
for letter in name:
    if letter in letters_to_code:
        letters_to_code[letter]()
"""


done()
```